# How do you handle objects created at runtime in conjunction with Dependency Injection frameworks?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I love dependency injection frameworks and how they allow me to request the one object everything starts with. All the wiring is made on the first request for that "master" object.
However, there are objects that should be created during runtime, e.g. based on user input. And sometimes those newly created objects should be shared among other objects created by the framework.

My current approach is to have "uninitialized" objects injected by the framework. During runtime I set up the object with setter methods as soon as possible.

What I don't like with this approach is that the setter methods are really invoked only once and should then never be touched again. This prevents me from declaring the fields as final. I don't now how to create the object not before all necessary information is available without losing all the benefits from the DI framework.

I'm new to DI. Are there any good patterns for this?

---

Example:

```
// The service is used through out the application
interface Service {
  makeRequest()
}
```

What I want to do after user typed in credentials:

```
new ConcreteService(username, password)
// but now I need to inject the concrete servive manually everywhere I need it!
```

What I'm currently doing:

```
interface Service {
   makeRequest()
   setCredentials(username, password)
}
// service can be injected by framework, but I don't like setter methods
// that much (and they can pollute the interface)
```

Comment: as I understand correctly, the main problem is that you should "update/recreate" already "wired" objects through all application?

Comment: @Ernusc I added an example

Comment: It smells a flawed design. Can you make some arguments why you need to inject concrete service through all application according to input? Normally, there should be an orchestration service which populates/calls/forwards to one or more providers/delegators. Also, according to your example, "authentication" should be a cross-cutting concern, so it must have an orchestration to manage different auth ways! Based on your requirements, it seems that you want to eliminate orchestration class which IMHO is a bad design :)

Comment: Well, maybe the Service example is not that well suited. You mean I should have a class (keeping the not so good example above)  "ServiceContainer" on which my application code depends, so I need to inject the ConcreteService only once to this container (via a setter method)?

Comment: Your use case are to inject managed IoC objects to not managed?

Comment: No, the other way round. I was hoping unmanaged objects can be injected  to managed objects in other ways than using setter methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of my experience with dependency injection is with C# but I believe the concept remains the same no matter what language.

What I understand from the original poster is that he's trying to "persist" information within the dependency injection container in order to retrieve the information at a later time.

The problem with this approach is that, in a multi-threaded scenario, there's the possibility that the dependency that you are using to persist information has its values overwritten by another thread. This can happen because the dependency injection container usually holds a single instance of the object which is returned to you whenever you need it. Therefore, you need to make sure that your design is thread safe.

In my experience, using the dependency injection container to maintain state is bad.

What you register in your dependency injection container are the objects that provide a "service" and that don't maintain any state.

Objects that you use to hold information are usually business objects. These business objects should just be instantiated with "new" (without the dependency injection container), populate them in the usual manner (with setters or initialization method or constructor) and just be passed on as part of the signature of the operations that your services expose.

Note: You can register your dependency as "transient" which would tell the dependency injection container to return a new instance every time you ask for the dependency. This would avoid the need to use the "new" keyword explicitly and give you more control when writing unit tests with a mocking framework.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it would be to use a factory.

For example, say you had this class...

```
public class UserBean {

    private int userId;
    private UserService userService;
    // other resources / dependency fields etc

    public UserBean(int userId, UserService userService, ...other dependencies...) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.... = ...
    }

    // ...getter for userId maybe etc...

    // Some method that uses the user's data AND the component/service you want to inject from Spring...
    public void incrementHitCount() {
        userService.incrementHitCount(userId);
    }
}
```

...where "userService" is something you want that is managed by the IoC container. If you then have a component that needs to create one of these, e.g....

```
@Component
public class UserHitCountIncrementerThing {
    public ResponseBean doThatThing(HttpServletRequest request) {
         int userId = request.<get the user Id from it...>
         UserBean userbean = new UserBean(userId, /* need dependencies here! */);
         ...do stuff...
    }
}
```

You could just @Autowire in all of the services to this bean, or you could create a factory and just @Autowire one, for example...

```
@Component
public class UserBeanFactory {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService
    //...other @Autowired dependencies...

    public UserBean createUser(int userId) {
       return new UserBean(userService, ...etc..., userId);
    }
}
```

Now just use this where you need it, e.g...

```
@Component
public class UserHitCountIncrementerThing {
    @Autowired
    private UserBeanFactory userFactory;

    public ResponseBean doThatThing(HttpServletRequest request) {
         int userId = request.<get the user Id from it...>
         UserBean userbean = userFactory.createUser(userId);
         ...do stuff...
    }
}
```

Is this what you were getting at?

Hope this helps.

Comment: UserBeanFactory still has the same service instance.

Comment: @Emusc - yes, but if you needed to get a "UserBean" in more than one component, you wouldn't have to wire in all of the dependencies into those if you see what I mean. (Imagine if UserBean needed 4 dependencies from the IoC container injkecting into it)

Comment: @Emusc - Have I misunderstood? Does it need to be a different one for each UserBean?

Comment: it's maybe me. I has been looking at this situation from two different points. If OP wants IoC managed objects wire to not managed then it's the right way you have already shown :)

Comment: First of, I though OP wants lazy prototype references

Comment: @Emusc - you should probably stick an answer in elaborating on this that demonstrates this?